# I'm not able to save the response of view result tree under HTTP test Script recorder in JMeter)

Tags: jmeter

I want to save the responses of view results tree under HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder to access the recording long for next time.

for this I fallowed below steps but getting an error.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQATt.png)
Here in the above Image I clicked on Browse under the write results to file/ Read from file and enter the file name demo.xml then clicking on open but after this It is throwing the error: "Error Loading Results file.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x7R1.png)
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1nKD.png)

Comment: please add more screenshots / error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the request/response details written into a file you need to provide the file name in the [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) before running your test/recording.

I would recommend using [Recording Template](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)  which provides pre-configured test elements you need to perform a recording, you can access it by choosine `File- Templates - Recording` from JMeter's main menu:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If i close JMeter and open again this recording.xml file I'm not able to see the responces in that file.